# How does Appraise work on a magic item?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

If a magic item looks like a common item, do I use the DC for common items or "rare or exotic" items?

Answer (score 3):

A magic item that a possessor doesn't know is a magic item should be the subject of an Appraise skill check according to the rarity of whatever mundane item that magic item seems to be. In fact, for example, valuable plot information can gained by an adventurer using the Appraise skill to determine the once-or-now mundane item's creator's race (DC 10), a skill use for Appraise briefly mentioned in the *Rules Compendium* (10).

But until a magic item's full powers are known, this DM doesn't allow a PC to know a magic item's price. It's once a magic item's full powers *are* known—the PC has used on it the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell [*identify*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#identify) [div] (*Player's Handbook* 243), for example, or examined it carefully using an *artificer's monocle* (*Magic Item Compendium* 72) (1,500 gp; 0 lbs.)—that this DM has always just straight-up told the PC the price of that magic item. I've never participated in nor run a campaign that handled things differently.

While I guess a stricter DM *could* opt to have an *identify* effect *only* reveal "all magic properties of a [a] magic item" and *not* the magic item's mundane properties like price and weight *then* have the PC make Appraise, Knowledge (arcana), or Spellcraft skill checks to determine the magic item's mundane information like price—and I've seen nothing in the rules to *deny* the DM that option—, that'd make dealing with magic items *really* complicated.

The *3.5* magic item system tacitly encourages magic items be routinely bought and sold, acquired and discarded, at a fairly good clip. I imagine a campaign in which the value of magic items is *not* revealed even after they've been analyzed would run much more slowly if none of the PCs had the appropriate skills. (That is, I imagine players in such a campaign would end up worrying more about getting screwed over by merchants than about ridding the village of wereweasels or rescuing the prince of Kidnappedagain Cove!)

An [epic skill use of the Appraise skill](http://dndsrd.net/epicSkills.html#appraise) allows a mundane [*detect magic*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#detect-magic) effect, the skill trick Magical Appraisal (*Complete Scoundrel* 87) permits a creature 1/day to essentially use an *identify* effect, and the feat Appraise Magic (Save My Game Web column ["Identifying Magic Items"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/sg/20051125a)) allows a creature to substitute Appraise skill checks for Spellcraft skill checks when using the Web column's rules that expand the Spellcraft skill's capacity for identifying magic items. However, so far as I'm aware, there's no process for discerning the price of a magic item using the Appraise skill, the game, I think, assuming an adventurer knows a magic item's price *as a magic item* once the magic item's successfully identified.

Comment: Considering that the "price" is actually the market value, and that most DM's don't want to deal with market fluctuations... there is no real reason to obfuscate the price.